# Can not Clean Project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

When tried to clean the project using options provided by Android Studio IDE. I get following errors.

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android
>   Package Builder' on project 'appcompat_v7'. Problems encountered while
>   deleting resources. Could not delete 'C:\Users\Felix Manford
>   Esq\Documents\Workspace\Ghtourwall\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files. Could not delete:
>   C:\Users\Felix Manford
>   Esq\Documents\Workspace\Ghtourwall\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources. Could not delete
>   'C:\Users\Felix Manford
>   Esq\Documents\Workspace\Ghtourwall\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files. Could not delete:
>   C:\Users\Felix Manford
>   Esq\Documents\Workspace\Ghtourwall\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar.

I observed it was right after i set up my image button; which i don't get because i did everything correctly.

Comment: make sure those files are not set to read-only.

Comment: The error specifically says it can't delete a file. So use your troubleshooting skills and make sure those files are deletable.

Answer (score 1):

> I observed it was right after i set up my image button; which i don't
>   get cos i did everything correctly

No This is not due to this issue. The error is not a syntax issue, It is a development environment's Build issue.

There are several things that you can do to kill the process that prevents the cleaning of the application to work.

1. Close the IDE and then start it again. This will kill the currently running Gradle build tasks. which will prevent these jar files being deleted during the clean up.
2. You can invalidate the IDE using the following option,

[image]

3. Even if that is not working, You can kill all the JVM processes that runs on your computer using the task manager,

[image]

4. If that does not solve the issue, You can try restarting the computer as last resort.
5. I do not expect that you get to this one. But If any of these things did not work, then there is something wrong with your IDE or JVM, Try to reinstall IDE and see,

Comment: The reason I'm thinking it might be the image button is, when I delete it the on click listener code for the button the app runs perfectly